# SQLite python получить данные, если слово содержится в ячейке базы

Tags: python, sql

Всем привет!

Допустип у нас есть БД, и там поля ( айди, фраза, деньги ),и есть запись ( 30, "привет мир фраза1 фраза2", 30), так вот, надо запросом к БД ( или в скрипте ), сделать так, что искало слово "фраза1" ( text in str не подойдёт )

Comment: Когда задаете вопрос, необходимо предоставить "Минимальный воспроизводимый пример".
Для справки: Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Для вашего сценария это означает следующее:
(1) DDL и образец вставки данных, т.е. CREATE table(s) плюс операторы INSERT, в SQL.
(2) Что вам нужно сделать, т.е. логика и ваш SQL код пытающийся ее реализовать.
(3) Желаемый результат на основе примера данных в #1 выше.
(4) Ваша база данных (СУБД) и ее версия.

Comment: sqlite3, результат: получение строки из бд при выполненом условии описанном выше

Comment: ## 1-3, не предоставлены.

Comment: 1) CREATE TABLE "" (
 "id" INTEGER,
 "text" INTEGER
);
2) Запрос к базе данных, который ищет слова в поле text и возвращает строку с найденным словом.
Например есть 3 записи: 
2.1) id: 423, text: "ДР Уфа"
2.2) id: 53, text: "кудрово"
2.3) id: 4, text: "кликбейт"
Далее делаем запрос который ищет слово "ДР"  и возврощает строку.
3) Строка id: 423, text: "ДР"
Заметьте, в кудрово содержится ДР, и запрос не должен возвращать эту строку, только если есть отдельное слово ДР

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующее.

**SQL**

```
SELECT * FROM table_name
WHERE column LIKE '%фраза1%'
```

Comment: возвращает строку со словом куДРово,  а оно мне не нужно, нужно только ДР

Comment: Мы вернулись на круги своя. ## 1-3, не предоставлены. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте исходный пост и добавьте.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, вы подали мне идею 
Получилось так:
`SELECT * FROM company WHERE name_camp LIKE 'ДР %' OR name_camp LIKE 'ДР%';`

Comment: Рад слышать, что у тебя все работает.